# Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality for functions $f,g\in L^2(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I learned in my abstract linear algebra class that suppose $u,v\in V$, then $$|\langle u,v\rangle| \le \|u\|\|v\| .$$ The way I always remember is that the dot product of two vectors is less or equal than the product of their norms.

In the case that $V$ is a real vector space of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[-1,1]$, the inner product of $f,g$ is $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 fg dx$$ and Cauchy-Schwartz inequality implies $$|\langle f,g\rangle|^2=(\int_{-1}^1 fg~ dx)^2 \le  \int_{-1}^1 f^2 dx\int g^2 dx = \|f\|^2 \|g\|^2,$$ which aligns with the above general statement.

However, consider the following case. $(X,m,\mu)$ is a measure space. Let $E\in \mathfrak{M}$ and let $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$. And set $L^2(E,\mu)$ with distance function 2-norm. Let $f\in L^2(E,\mu), g \in L^2(E,\mu)$. The Cauchy-inequality given by Rudin on page 326 is $$ \int_X |fg| d\mu\le \|f\|\|g\|$$.

I'm confused about the left-hand side. Because $\int_X |fg| d\mu$ does seems to be the inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int f\bar g ~d\mu$.

Is it correct to think that the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in the last case is not exactly aligned with the general statement mentioned in the very beginning?

Comment: Just apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $|f|$ and $|g|$ to get Rudin's inequality.

Comment: Did you mean
$$
|\langle f,g\rangle|^2=(\int_{-1}^1 fg~ dx)^2\ {\huge \le }  \int_{-1}^1 f^2 dx\int g^2 dx = \|f\|^2 \|g\|^2,
$$

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes, and I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity given by Rudin is $\|fg\|_1 \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2$ which is equivalent to Cauchy's inequality:

$\implies\quad$
$
|\langle f, g \rangle|
= \left| \int f \bar{g} \right|
\leq \int |f \bar{g}|
= \int |fg|
= \|fg\|_1
\leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2.
$

$\impliedby\quad$
$
\|fg\|_1
= \int |fg|
= \int |f||g|
= \langle |f|, |g| \rangle
\leq \| |f| \|_2 \, \| |g| \|_2
= \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2.
$